# C# does not receive any response values from Jenkins

Tags: c#, rest, jenkins

I'm calling Jenkins jobs from C# using the WebClient class and I'm not receiving any response even though the Jenkins job is triggering and executing properly.  I need to read the headers to get the queue number and things like that, so I'm confused as to why this is happening.  Below is my code, which works just fine except for "response" is always an empty string; not null, just an empty string:'

'

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
            {

                string url = "http://url:8080/job/CloudTeam/job/Azure/job/Create-Azure-VM/buildWithParameters";

                string queryString = "HOSTNAME=" + virtualMachine.Hostname + "&IPADDRESS=" + virtualMachine.IPAddress + "&RESOURCEGROUP=" + virtualMachine.ResourceGroup + "&STORAGEACCOUNT=" + virtualMachine.StorageAccount + "&BASEIMAGE=" + virtualMachine.BaseImage;

                string password = "password";
                string username = "user";

                string basicAuthToken = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
                wb.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + basicAuthToken;
                wb.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                wb.Headers.Add("user", "user:password");

                string response = wb.UploadString(url, queryString);
                return response; <-- always an empty string
            }
```

'

Comment: Does `UploadString` send a GET or POST?  I'm guessing you don't need to upload a string, perhaps use HttpClient/GetAsync instead?

Comment: I'm using Postman to send a post to the URL, which is http://machine:port/api/va/buildvirtualmachine.  I'm sending the data as JSON, which then creates a VirtualMachine object which is used to fill out the needed values.  This all seems to work just fine, Jenkins builds the requested machine.

Comment: WebRequest and WebResponse have always worked for me with rest api's but I have not used the Jenkins api.

Comment: Could you try to consume the jenkins endpoint using curl in order to validate if the error is in c# or something in jenkins?

Comment: the UploadString method is supposed to return a string.  Is there another data type it can return?

Comment: I seem to get a 201 response from a curl



` upload completely sent off: 121 out of 121 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
HTTP/1.1 201 Created`